# Process AWS S3 events using AWS lambda [JAVA]?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I want to write a lambda function which would print the output of the given s3 file. The lambda function would be triggered every time a new file is uploaded to S3. I have found various examples for Node.js but haven't been able to figure out how to do it with Java.

```
public void handleRequest(S3Event input, Context context){

  //How to read the file using input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Lambda function isn't passed the file, just the information about the file. You would need to [use the AWS SDK for Java](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/index.html) to open the file, just like you would access a file on S3 using Java running anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go through this tutorial, it should help: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html